# How can I receive firebase messages using python (or API)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, messaging

I have a fleet of devices running python and need to be able to send messages to/from them each individually. I know that it is possible to send a message to an individual InstanceID token, but I can't figure out how to register a device to get an InstanceID token and then listen for messages.

I was hoping to have something like https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/index.html#subscribing, where it would listen for messages for just that client. What I want is

```
client = messaging.client()
while true:
    msg = client.getMessage()
    print(msg)
```

I'm open to doing it with the REST API too, but can't find a way to do it there either. I've look at the [python docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging) and the [API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages).

I'm open to other ideas to accomplish this, like pub/sub, but that doesn't seem to support the individual device mapping. I could have a topic per device, but there's an upper limit of topics that may be too low.

Answer (score 1):

While **sending** messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging is possible from most platforms, **listening for messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging is only supported through the official SDKs that are available for Android, iOS and client-side JavaScript**. There are no SDKs, or documented API for receiving messages on other platforms.

Given that you tagged with `google-cloud-pubsub` that (while unrelated to FCM) would probably be a good protocol/API to consider for delivering messages to Python clients. Within the Firebase suite of products, something like Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore would be other options - as both also support realtime listeners.